# We think a former employee stole our code and started his own company with it. What can we do?

Tags: intellectual-property, software

## What can we do?

With respect to this topic, I found [this](https://techcrunch.com/2012/04/26/facebook-hacker-tells-all/) anecdote.  But I don't work for Facebook, and we have nowhere near the clout or the user base they do.  I'm not 100% sure why Facebook was able to nail this kid so harshly, but obviously billions of people use Facebook whereas our smaller company is not such a security risk

Nonetheless, can we sue our former employee?  I'm surprised this kid even got jailed for it; I'm not interested in putting my former friend and colleague in prison.  We just want them to stop stealing our business

We have a one-man legal team and are just a startup

## Other resources I've looked at:

1. https://embeddedgurus.com/stack-overflow/2012/02/why-you-really-shouldnt-steal-source-code/
2. http://www.ipwatchdog.com/2013/02/16/a-guide-to-patenting-software-getting-started/id=35629/
3. https://www.quora.com/Why-don%E2%80%99t-people-just-steal-open-source-code-do-a-quick-restructuring-and-sell-it-commercially-as-their-own-Is-there-a-way-to-prove-if-you-think-someone-is-using-your-OS-code-in-a-closed-source-code-format-for-profit
4. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/154155/should-you-keep-a-copy-of-all-the-code-you-write
5. https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2012-05-29/chinese-citizen-pleads-guilty-to-stealing-treasury-software

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Based on a look at that article, you should be able to punish that employee.  Our Intellectual Property systems are based around the theories of [Locke](https://cyber.harvard.edu/people/tfisher/iptheory.pdf) and others.  Society does not function well if individuals cannot keep the wealth they create, and that Facebook case shows how severely a student was punished merely for *obtaining* source code, whereas your coworker has actually gone and tried to financially benefit from copying your code.

If a lawyer has any input, that would be helpful.  I'm not sure how you can actually go about enforcing your legal rights, given your startups "lean" nature

Answer (score 3):

You should talk to an attorney, but based on what you've provided, there are potential claims for copyright infringement, trade secret misappropriation, conversion, unfair trade practices, and probably quite a bit more.

Answer (score 2):

What you are describing is a copyright violation and you could sue the former employee for violating your copyright in the code if you could prove its source.